# Id like to group by number of days (+ or -) and use min date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
ID        Date          Count
1,        2014-05-01    1
1,        2014-05-04    1 
1,        2014-05-10    1
2,        2014-05-02    1
2,        2014-05-03    1
2,        2014-05-09    1
```

if I was to group where the time difference +/- 5 days, this would become

```
ID        Date          Count
1,         2014-05-01    2
1,         2014-05-10    1
2,         2014-05-02    2
2,         2014-05-09    1
```

Is this possible in Sequel Server 2012? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should actually make an attempt at solving this problem yourself and then come back here with a specific problem if it doesn't work.

Comment: What would your desired output be if your data included the row (1,'2014-05-07',1)? That's within 5 days of the 05-04 record, but too far from 05-01 to be included. Does 05-04 participate in 2 groups?

Comment: Apologies, I may have confused things in my wording, If there is a gap of 5 days or more between dates then a new group would be created (still grouped by ID)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to start a new group when there is a gap of five days.  So, if you had a record with (1, 2014-05-07), then you would have only one group for `1`.

If so, the following will work:

```
select id, min(date), sum(count)
from (select t.*, sum(HasGap) over (partition by id order by date) as grpid
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when datediff(day,
                                       lag(date) over (partition by id order by date),
                                       date) < 5
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as HasGap
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grpid;
```